# MediaView is not returning different snapshots

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I am able to get snapshots of video when played using the following;

```
mediaView.snapshot(null, null);
```

Now I want to take snapshots with certain duration gaps like the following:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    Media media = null;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    MediaView mediaView = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Video Snapshot");
        
        media = new Media(new File("filePathTo.mp4").toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        
        mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            writeToFile(0.0);
            writeToFile(1000.0);
            writeToFile(10000.0);;
            writeToFile(50000.0);
          }
      });
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 480, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        
        mediaPlayer.play();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    
    private void writeToFile(Double double1) {
        
        mediaView.getMediaPlayer().seek( Duration.millis(double1) );
        
        WritableImage writableImage = mediaView.snapshot(null, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream  byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ImageIO.write( SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage( writableImage, new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) ), "png", byteOutput );
            byteOutput.writeTo(new FileOutputStream( Paths.get(double1.toString()).toFile() + ".png" ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

But now I get the same image and not different images, although the writableImage objects returned are different. Check the files 0.0.png, 1000.0.png, 10000.0.png, 50000.0.png files. All appears same. How could I get different snapshots?

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Most likely the new pixels haven't been rendered in the `MediaView` by the time you take a snapshot. A solution might depend on your current implementation, so please provide a [mre] as requested.

Comment: Try taking the second snapshot in a platform run later call (just a guess), that will allow the JavaFX system to render the new frame before you snapshot.

Comment: @jewelsea, calling snapshot in platform run later isn't helpful. All of them are same.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that the new pixels aren't rendered by the time you take the snapshot. You need to give JavaFX time to render the video. The following example works for me:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        var player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(Path.of("video.mp4").toUri().toString()));
        player.setAutoPlay(true);

        var view = new MediaView(player);
        player.setOnPlaying(() -> {
            snapshotVideo(view, 0)
                    .thenCompose(unused -> snapshotVideo(view, 1000))
                    .thenCompose(unused -> snapshotVideo(view, 2000))
                    .thenCompose(unused -> snapshotVideo(view, 3000));
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Pane(view), 1000, 650));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Video Snapshot");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> snapshotVideo(MediaView view, double seekMillis) {
        var future = new CompletableFuture<Void>();

        view.getMediaPlayer().seek(Duration.millis(seekMillis));
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            var fxImage = view.snapshot(null, null);
            var bufImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(fxImage, null);

            var filename = String.format("snapshot-%.0f.png", seekMillis);
            try (var out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(filename))) {
                ImageIO.write(bufImage, "png", out);
                future.complete(null);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                future.completeExceptionally(ex);
            }
        });

        return future;
    }
}
```

It uses a combination of `Platform#runLater(Runnable)` and `CompletableFuture`.

- It seeks to the desired time and then runs the snapshot+save code in a `runLater` call. This is an attempt to give JavaFX time to render the new seeked-to frame. I don't know if this is guaranteed to work. If I'm not mistaken, the JavaFX media implementation has one or more background threads for processing the audio/video. But I don't know if those threads can "fall behind". Also, it's possible that seeking far enough ahead could lead to buffering. So, you might have to handle that by listening to the `status` property of the `MediaPlayer`.
- It uses `CompletableFuture` to make sure the next snapshot is not taken until the previous one has been taken and saved. It would probably be a good idea to move the image-saving code to a background thread. The important part, I think, is that the snapshot has been fully taken before you try to take the next one.

I also start taking these snapshots when the player is *playing*, not just *ready*. Not sure if that matters. I'm not even sure that the player needs to be playing for this to work.

And finally, the JavaFX Media API is probably not the best tool to use for this job. If I wanted frames from an MP4 video at different times, I would try to find a library that can just grab those frames straight from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Slaw for your answer. When I tried your code, it gave different results every time I ran it. The problem is definitely that the new pixels aren't rendered by the time the snapshots are taken. runLater and CompletableFuture are both providing some time for the process to render which sometimes are sufficient as maybe what happened in your system. But they are no way aware of if the process is really ready for snapshot-ing. What worked for me is that I replaced the player.setOnPlaying with the following:

```
player.setOnMarker(event -> {
    snapshotVideo(view, event.getMarker().getValue().toMillis());
});
```

And also modified the snapshotVideo method in the following way:

```
private void snapshotVideo(MediaView view, double duration) {
    var fxImage = view.snapshot(null, null);
    var bufImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(fxImage, null);

    var filename = String.format("snapshot-%.0f.png", duration);
    try (var out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of(filename))) {
        ImageIO.write(bufImage, "png", out);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I did was removed both runLater and CompletableFuture. I am depending on Player.setOnMarker() method for assurance of the process to be ready for snapshot-ing.